# Annotations for Java enum singleton

Tags: enums, annotations, singleton, java

As Bloch states in Item 3 ("Enforce the singleton property with a private constructor or an enum type") of *Effective Java 2nd Edition*, **a single-element enum type is the best way to implement a singleton**. Unfortunately the old private constructor pattern is still very widespread and entrenched, to the point that many developers don't understand what I'm doing when I create enum singletons.

A simple `// Enum Singleton` comment above the class declaration helps, but it still leaves open the possibility that another programmer could come along later and add a second constant to the enum, breaking the singleton property. For all the problems that the private constructor approach has, in my opinion it is somewhat more self-documenting than an enum singleton.

I think what I need is an annotation which both states that the enum type is a singleton and ensures at compile-time that only one constant is ever added to the enum. Something like this:

```
@EnumSingleton // Annotation complains if > 1 enum element on EnumSingleton
public enum EnumSingleton {
   INSTANCE;
}
```

Has anyone run across such an annotation for standard Java in public libraries anywhere? Or is what I'm asking for impossible under Java's current annotation system?

**UPDATE**

One workaround I'm using, at least until I decide to actually bother with rolling my own annotations, is to put `@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")` directly in front of the `INSTANCE` field. It does a decent job of making the code look distinct from a straightforward enum type.

Comment: Best way must be in the first place simple and clear from my point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of such an annotation in public java libraries, but you can define yourself such a compile time annotation to be used for your projects. Of course, you need to write an annotation processor for it and invoke somehow [APT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/GettingStarted.html) (with [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [maven](http://maven.apache.org/)) to check your `@EnumSingleton` annoted enums at compile time for the intended structure.

Here is a resource on how to write and use [compile time annotations](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17961.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this -

```
public class SingletonClass {
    private SingletonClass() {
        // block external instantiation
    }

    public static enum SingletonFactory {
        INSTANCE {
            public SingletonClass getInstance() {
                return instance;
            }
        };

        private static SingletonClass instance = new SingletonClass();
        private SingletonFactory() {
        }

        public abstract SingletonClass getInstance();
    }
}
```

And you can access in some other class as -

```
SingletonClass.SingletonFactory.INSTANCE.getInstance();
```

Comment: Thanks! That's an interesting approach to blend in the benefits of private constructors. Certainly makes the fact that it's a singleton much more obvious. :)

Something else that occurs to me is to put a check on the length of EnumSingleton.values() in the enum's private default constructor. Then I can at least throw a RuntimeException if some careless person does try and add another constant to the enum at some point.

Comment: @AndrewBissell I think that's a better candidate for a unit test as unit tests are suppose to help describe a class's behavior.

Comment: @Jazzepi Right you are! I got a nice stack trace with an "invokeExplosively" line in it when I tried reading the length of values() before the enum had been initialized. :) So much for that idea.